# How do I recursively find and replace only in files named index.php on Linux webserver?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to perform a recursive find and replace on a Linux webserver (searches 100,000+ files, but it takes so long that my SSH session times out. Is there a way to *only* search files named "index.php"?  This would cut down on execution time dramatically.

Here is the command I'm using:

```
$     find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i “s%Apples%Oranges%g”
```

Comment: `find ... -name index.php`?

Comment: If the remote machine has multiple cores/processors/threads that you can highjack, then see the remote `xargs` supports the `-P or --maxprocs` option. Then you can run multiple `sed` sessions, which should speed up your processing significantly. Good luck.

Comment: You can find and replace using perl `find . -name "index.php" | xargs perl -pi -e 's/Apples/Oranges/g' `

Comment: Also, if you session times out so quickly, consider using `screen` or `tmux` or `dtach` or something.

Comment: Missed this before, you're sample shows "smart-quotes", i.e.  `“ ... ”` The shell won't understand that, you need to use plain keyboard dbl-quotes, i.e. `"...."`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `find` command to add the `-name` option:

```
find . -name 'index.php' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/Apples/Oranges/g"
```

(I put the `-name` predicate first, on the principle that it's marginally faster than anything which needs to `stat()` files, but it may well be that `find` optimizes for that anyway.)

Also, consider a parallel invocation of `xargs`; e.g. with GNU `xargs`:

```
find . -name 'index.php' -type f -print0 \
  | xargs --max-procs `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` -0 sed -i "s/Apples/Oranges/g"
```